Did Arjun see an invisible warrior in the battlefield?
I remember that I read somewhere that Arjun saw a lightening fast warrior in the battlefield, who would kill Arjuna's enemies before Arjuna's arrows would hit them. Only Arjun could see this warrior and it seemed like Arjun was the one who killed the enemies to everyone else.
Arjun shared this with Krishna and Krishna said that the warrior is actually Rudra.
I also remember something along the lines that Rudra hates arrogance and so, is there in the battlefield to destroy people who were consumed by arrogance.
I searched about the same on the internet today, but I found nothing. Is my memory incorrect? I remember reading this years ago, and cannot believe that my memory could be incorrect.

This question is kind of unclear do you want a reference or what are you looking for?

@Haridasa I am not sure that my memory is correct, so I just wanted to confirm if there are any references about what I shared.
In short, yes, I am looking for a reference.

Ask for references


Lord Krishna says that Rudra who is born from Krishna's rage was moving infront of Arjuna's chariot -


When the battle presented itself, there was a being who advanced in
front of you. Know him to be Rudra Kapardin, the god of the gods. He
is also known as Kala and he was born out of my rage. He had already
slain all your enemies.


1658 (330), Moksha Dharma Parva, Mahabharata.

